# grouped discrete data v.s. grouped continuous data

Tags: statistics

How to distinguish grouped discrete data and grouped continuous data?
I have googled two terms. It seems to me that they are refer to the same thing. I will be appreciated if someone tells me the difference between two types of data.

Comment: More context would help others to assist you.

Comment: One method for discrete data is to put cut-points between possible values. In the US it seems to be common practice to use intervals closed on the left $[a,b)$ so that axis label $a$ is included in interval to the right. In the EU it seems to be more common to use $(a,b],$ which matches well with the definition of CDF. There are many different schemes for choosing the number of bins for intervals in a histogram. Google 'histogram intervals' and such to see lots of opinions online.

Comment: Discrete data take only a finite or countable number of values.(In practical situations, finite). Continuous data can take any value in a specified interval of the real line. (In practice it's often a finite interval, and real values must be rounded to a specified number of decimal places.) The distinction can get blurred; Heights of people might be theoretically continuous, but get rounded to the nearest inch (or cm) and so are sometimes considered discrete.

Answer (score 0):

Some demos of histogram binning in R.

**Discrete:**  Data from $\mathsf{Binom}(n=10,p=.3).$ Control breaks to fall at half integers.

```
set.seed(625)  # seed for reproducibility
x = rbinom(100, 10, .3)
hist(x, br=seq(-.5, 10.5), col="skyblue2", 
   label=T, ylim=c(0, 27))
table(x)
x
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  8 
 2 11 22 25 24 12  3  1
```

[image]

Simulated sum when three fair dice are rolled. Based on a million rolls of three dice.

```
set.seed(1776)
s = replicate( 10^6, sum(sample(1:6, 3, rep=T)) )
table(s)
s
     3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10 
  4634  13944  27446  46127  69501  96782 115304 125292 
     11     12     13     14     15     16     17     18 
 125641 115688  97501  69387  46498  27907  13707   4641 

hist(s, prob=T, br=(1:18)+.5, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

**Continuous.** Small sample from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100, \sigma=15).$ Uses R's default binning.
Parameter `prob=T` makes a histogram so that the total area of its bars is unity. The density function of the population distribution is shown in red. (R rounds normal values to 7 decimal places.)

```
set.seed(1234)
x = rnorm(50, 100, 15)
hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
curve(dnorm(x, 100, 15), add=T, col="red")
rug(x)  # tick marks
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  64.81   85.18   91.97   93.20   99.42  136.24
```

[image]

A larger sample gives a better fit to the population distribution.

```
set.seed(2019)
x = rnorm(1000, 100, 15)
hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
curve(dnorm(x, 100, 15), add=T, col="red")
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  51.46   89.09   98.02   98.83  108.98  153.12
```

[image]

Comment: Did you use Python matplotlib to create those graphs?

Comment: No.  Just the basic graphics in R; no special Libraries. [This recent Answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4105614/what-is-the-cost-of-reconstructing-a-discrete-probability-distribution-from-sam/4105870#4105870) has R code for somewhat similar graphs.