# What is the cost of reconstructing a discrete probability distribution within a given error?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, information-theory

I'm aware that there are several methods to estimate the probability distribution from samples (e.g. [density estimation methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_estimation)). However, I haven't been able to find the actual asymptotic costs of these methods, and I'm not sure whether these methods can be applied to the case of discrete probability distributions.

Given a discrete probability distribution $p$ on $[n]\equiv \{1,...,n\}$, I'm looking for the number of samples required to construct a distribution $q$ on $[n]$ such that $\|p-q\|_1\le\epsilon$ ($\|\cdot\|_1$ denoting here the $\ell_1$ distance).
In other words, how many samples are needed to estimate the correct probability distribution within a given error $\epsilon$?

I've recently read the statement (in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.00814), second paragraph of introduction) that the cost of doing this is $\Theta(n/\epsilon^2)$, but if this is a well-known result I haven't been able to find a good explanation for it.

I suppose the naive reconstruction method would be to build the histogram corresponding to the samples (that is, count the fraction of samples corresponding to each $i=1,...,n$). However, I'm not sure whether this method is optimal for the purpose, or how many samples would be required to achieve a given estimation error with it.

Estimates using distances other than the $\ell_1$ one are of course also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Upon some reflection, here is what I think might be a possible solution.

Suppose the true distribution is $\newcommand{\bs}[1]{{\boldsymbol{#1}}}\bs p\equiv(p_1,...,p_n)$, and we are drawing $N>0$ samples from it.
This amounts to be drawing samples from the [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution), call it $\mathrm{Multinomial}(N,\bs p)$.

If $X\sim \mathrm{Multinomial}(N,\bs p)$, then the possible outcomes of $X$ are (representable by) sequences of $N$ integers $x_i\in[n]\equiv \{1,..., n\}$, with $i=1,...,N$.
Because our goal is to estimate $\bs p$, we are interested in the number of times each $k\in [n]$ occurred in a given instance of $X$.
Denote the corresponding estimator with $\hat N_i$.
We know that
$$\mathrm{Pr}(\hat N_i = N_i) = \binom{N}{\bs N}\bs p^{\bs N}
\equiv \binom{N}{N_1\cdots N_n} p_1^{N_1}\cdots p_n^{N_n},$$
where $\binom{N}{\bs N}\equiv \frac{N!}{N_1!\cdots N_n!}$ denotes the associated
multinomial coefficient.

The problem at hand can be formalised as the task of looking for a good estimator for the parameter $\bs p$. The intuition of using the histogram of the distribution for the purpose can be formalised in the choice of the estimators
$$\hat p_i \equiv \frac{\hat N_i}{N}.$$
We can then compute the first moments, to find:
$$\mathbb E[\hat p_i] = \frac{\mathbb E[\hat N_i]}{N} = p_i \qquad \text{(the estimator is unbiased)}, \\
\mathrm{Var}[\hat p_i] = \frac{\mathrm{Var}[\hat N_i]}{N^2} = \frac{p_i(1-p_i)}{N}.$$
We can now compute the estimator corresponding to the trace distance between estimated and true distribution. For $n=2$, this reads
$$\|\hat{\bs p}-\bs p\|_1 = |\hat p_1 - p_1 | + |\hat p_2-p_2| = 2|\hat p_1 - p_1|,$$
and thus, from [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality), we have
$$\mathrm{Pr}(\|\hat{\bs p}-\bs p\|_1 \ge \epsilon) \le
\frac{2\mathrm{Var}[\hat p_1]}{\epsilon^2}
= \frac{2p_1 (1-p_1)}{N \epsilon^2}.$$
Without making more assumptions about the probability distribution, we should probably take the worst-case scenario, and thus replace this with an identity. Shuffling terms around, we can then say that, in the worst-case scenario, to estimate a binary probability distribution $(p_1,p_2)$  with probability $t$ of committing an additive error $\epsilon$, we need a number of samples
$$N \ge \frac{2p_1(1-p_1)}{t\epsilon^2}.$$
If $p_1$ is unknown, as it would be in this context, we can again take the worst-case scenario, and get the bound $N\ge \frac{1}{2t \epsilon^2}$.

More generally, we can consider the *[total variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures)* $\delta(P,Q)$. This equals the maximum difference between the probabilities that $P$ and $Q$ assign to any given event.
We can then define the corresponding estimator, call it $\hat\delta=\hat\delta(\bs p)$, in the naive way:
$$\hat\delta(\bs p) = \max_{S\subseteq[n]}\sum_{i\in S} (\hat p_i-p_i)\equiv \max_{S\subseteq [n]}[\hat p(S) - p(S)],$$
where the maximum is taken over all subsets of $[n]\equiv\{1,...,n\}$.
Therefore, for all $S\subseteq [n]$, we have
$$\mathrm{Pr}(|\hat p(S) - p(S)|\ge \epsilon) \le \frac{\mathrm{Var}[\hat p(S)]}{\epsilon^2}.$$
We thus conclude that
$$\mathrm{Pr}(|\hat \delta(\bs p)| \ge \epsilon) \le \frac{\max_{S\subseteq [n]}\mathrm{Var}[\hat p(S)]}{\epsilon^2}
= \frac{1}{N\epsilon^2} \max_{S\subseteq [n]} C(S,p),$$
where
$C(S,p) \equiv \sum_{i\in S} p_i (1-p_i -2 \sum_{j>i} p_j)$.

Maximising $C(S, p)$ over $S$ and $p$, we again get a bound of the form $N\ge C/t\epsilon^2$, as in the previous case.

Comment: The last bit in your argument is unjustified - you can't conclude from the analysis presented that the chance of $\delta$ being large is controlled in this way because as far as I see nothing is handling the maximisation over $S$ in your argument. However this is not too hard - by Hoeffding's inequality, for any one $S$, the probability that $\hat{p}(S) - p(S)> \varepsilon$ is bounded as $\exp(-C N\varepsilon^2)$ where $C$ is a uniform constant. Then by the union bound $\mathbb{P}(\max_S \hat{p}(S) - p(S) > \varepsilon) \le |S| \exp(-CN\varepsilon^2) \le \exp( n - CN\varepsilon^2)$.

Comment: Also the linear dependence on $n$ is necessary in a minimax sense - consider the case where the laws may be uniform on some set $T \subset [1:n]$ of size $n/2$. Observing $o(n)$ samples can tell you at most $o(n)$ of the support points, which means that you have no way to distinguish between two slightly overlapping laws of this type, which means $\Omega(1)$ error in TV.

Comment: Oh, correction to the first comment, $|S|$ should be $|2^{[1:n]}| = 2^n$, which is merely the number of possible $S$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 thanks. I don't quite understand your argument though. I tried to add details to the statements in the last part of the answer. Do you think it makes more sense now? Still, Hoeffding might provide a better bound, I agree with that

Comment: No, that wasn't the point I was making - it's that you actually need to control $\mathbb{P}(\max_S \hat{p}(S) - p(S) \ge \varepsilon)$, while your analysis only controls $\max_S \mathbb{P}(\hat{p}(S) - p(S) \ge \varepsilon)$ (where $p(S) = \sum_{i \in S} p_i$ and similarly $\hat{p}$). The latter quantity is quite different from the former. The difference is similar to the difference between convergence in probability and convergence almost surely. Basically the worst $S$ can depend on the data (and so, on $\hat{p}$), which is not being accounted for in your argument.

Comment: If you want to use Tchebycheff, then at least union bound based analyses give very poor performance of $\mathbb{P}(\max_S \hat{p}(S) - p(S) \ge \varepsilon) \le 2^n/N\varepsilon^2$ - the dependence on $n$ is exponentially worse. The real utility of Hoeffding is that deviations are controlled exponentially well, which lets union bound based analyses to get to the optimal control on the sample complexity (how big $N$ needs to be in terms of $n,\varepsilon$), at least up to constants.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. One question though: once you have the $\exp(n-CN\epsilon^2)$ dependence, how do you turn this into a bound on $N$? Taking logs I'd get something like $\log t\le n - CN\epsilon^2$ which doesn't give a lower bound on $N$

Comment: An upper bound on probability of error of $\eta$ follows if $\exp(n - CN\varepsilon^2) < \eta,$ which occurs if $N \ge \frac{n + \log(1/\eta)}{C \varepsilon^2}$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 oh I see, you take the reciprocal and then the log; that works. By the way, if you want to write these things as an answer I'll gladly accept it. Also, I suppose these are standard calculations in some context? Do you know some reference where they are presented/discussed?

Answer (score 1):

As the sample sizes increases, density estimators do tend to come ever closer to the distribution of the population from which the sample was randomly samples. (However, depending on the kernel and bandwidth used, ECDFs can be
computationally intricate.)

Here is an illustration using samples of size 50, 500, 5000 from a gamma distribution with shape 5 and rate 0.1, so that the population mean is 50. The default kernel density estimator (KDE) in R was used to compute the density estimators (red). However, I am not sure how you propose to *measure* the fit of the KDE to the (possibly unknown) population density.

```
set.seed(2021)
x1 = rgamma(50, 5, .1)
x2 = rgamma(500, 5, .1)
x3 = rgamma(5000, 5, .1)
```

[image]

```
 par(mfrow=c(3,1))
 hist(x1, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.022), col="skyblue2", main="n=50, GAMMA(6,.1)")
  lines(density(x1), lwd=2, col="red")
  curve(dgamma(x,5,.1), add=T, lwd=2, lty="dotted")
 hist(x2, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.022), col="skyblue2", main="n=500, GAMMA(6,.1)")
  lines(density(x2), lwd=2, col="red")
  curve(dgamma(x,5,.1), add=T, lwd=2, lty="dotted")
 hist(x3, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.022), col="skyblue2", main="n=5000, GAMMA(6,.1)")
  lines(density(x3), lwd=2, col="red")
  curve(dgamma(x,5,.1), add=T, lwd=2, lty="dotted")
 par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

I don't know your goals, but it may be worth mentioning
that empirical CDFs (ECDFs) of samples often show a
better fit to population CDFs than histograms or density estimators show to population PDFs. Additionally, the
Kolmogorov-Smirnov test statistic $D$ measures the maximum
vertical distance between ECDF and CDF. As for computations cost, the ECDF essentially involves only sorting observations (and possibly plotting).

```
ks.test(x1, pgamma, 5, .1)

        One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x1
D = 0.089923, p-value = 0.7801
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

ks.test(x2, pgamma, 5, .1)

        One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x2
D = 0.037263, p-value = 0.4912
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

[image]

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 plot(ecdf(x1), col="skyblue", main="n=50")
  curve(pgamma(x,5,.1), add=T, lwd=2)
 plot(ecdf(x2), col="skyblue", main="n=500")
  curve(pgamma(x,5,.1), add=T, lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Comment: thanks. The goal is to be able to make statements about the number of samples required to estimate a distribution within a given error (defining some type of distance between the distributions). As shown in my answer, one way I thought about was considering an estimator for the total variation distance between the distribution and computing bounds for the probability of said distance being larger than a set amount. This way you can make statements of the form "you require at least this number of samples to estimate the distribution within this and this accuracy".

Comment: I have no idea if these sort of calculations are standard or not though, which was part of the reason for the question

Comment: Everything in my answer is more or less standard. Recommend using CDFs. There are various ways of quantifying distances between CDFs. One is max vertical distance as in K-S tests. Another is 'area between' CDFs. // You might want to look into 'goodness-of-fit= tests generally. Each sample will have its own quirks, but you may want to investigate 'power and sample size' of GOF tests. Power is probability of finding a specific kind of difference if it exists. Start by seeing what others have done before you try to invent the wheel again.

Comment: but CDFs are for continuous distributions no? I'm asking about discrete ones here. The K-S test you mention measures total vertical distance, which sounds like it would behave similarly to the total variation distance in the discrete case. But these are statistical tests. As far as I understand these answer different questions. I'm simply looking for a way to know the number of samples needed to get an estimation with a given accuracy. I thought this was an extremely basic question in this context, albeit I'm failing to find a straightforward answer (probably because I don't know the keywords)